# how to change stored procedure into table valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure that I  want to change into a table-valued function. I don't know how to create a table-valued function, please help me

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GENRATE_BATCHNO]
    @StrBatchNo varchar(200) output,
    @BatchNum bigint output,
    @RetType bigint output,
    @Fid int,
    @WcID int,
    @PrCompID bigint,
    @BsProductID bigint,
    @CreationDt datetime
as 
begin
    Declare @RestartFrom int, @BatchID bigint,@BatchMaxVal bigint,@ParaType int, @BatchValue varchar(50),@BatchFormat varchar(10),
    @Digits bigint,@BsParaID int,@StrBatchVal varchar(200),@StrVal varchar(200), @Type bigint, @Base int,@CompanyId int, @EffDate Date


    if exists (select 'x' from Tblbatchnosetting where baseprid=@BsProductID and PrCompID=@PrCompID and wcid=@WcID and effdate <= @CreationDt )
        Declare Cur_SttgMaster Cursor For Select RestartFrom,BatchID, Isnull(type,1),Base, CompanyId as Type,EffDate from Tblbatchnosetting where baseprid=@BsProductID and PrCompID=@PrCompID and wcid=@WcID 
        and effdate <= @CreationDt order by effdate desc
    else
    begin
        Declare Cur_SttgMaster Cursor For Select RestartFrom,BatchID, Isnull(Type,1) as Type,Base,CompanyId,EffDate  from Tblbatchnosetting where Companyid in (Select MfgID from TblBaseProduct where BsProductID=@BsProductID) and Base=1 and PrCompID=@PrCompID and wcid=@WcID
        and effdate <= @CreationDt order by effdate desc
    end

    open Cur_SttgMaster
    Fetch Next From Cur_SttgMaster Into @RestartFrom, @BatchID, @Type, @Base, @CompanyId,@EffDate
    Close Cur_SttgMaster
    Deallocate Cur_SttgMaster
    Set @RetType = @Type

    If @RestartFrom <> 0
        begin
        if @Base=1 
        begin 
            if @RestartFrom=1   --- Month ReStart
                Select @BatchMaxVal = isnull(Max(BatchNum),0) from tblbatchmaster where PrCompID=@PrCompID and BasePrid  in (Select Bsproductid from TblBaseProduct where Mfgid=@CompanyId) and Wcid=@Wcid 
                and fid=@Fid and month(CreatDate)=Month(@CreationDt)
            else if @RestartFrom=2  --- Yearly ReStart
                Select @BatchMaxVal = isnull(Max(BatchNum),0) from tblbatchmaster where PrCompID=@PrCompID and BasePrid in (Select Bsproductid from TblBaseProduct where Mfgid=@CompanyId) and Wcid=@Wcid 
                 and Year(CreatDate)=Year(@CreationDt) and CREATDATE >=@EffDate 
            else if @RestartFrom=3  --- never ReStart
                Select @BatchMaxVal = isnull(Max(BatchNum),0) from tblbatchmaster where PrCompID=@PrCompID and BasePrid in (Select Bsproductid from TblBaseProduct where Mfgid=@CompanyId) and Wcid=@Wcid 
        end 
        else if @Base=2
            BEGIN
            if @RestartFrom=1   --- Month ReStart
                Select @BatchMaxVal = isnull(Max(BatchNum),0) from tblbatchmaster where PrCompID=@PrCompID and BasePrid=@BsProductID and Wcid=@Wcid 
                and fid=@Fid and month(CreatDate)=Month(@CreationDt)
            else if @RestartFrom=2  --- Yearly ReStart
                Select @BatchMaxVal = isnull(Max(BatchNum),0) from tblbatchmaster where PrCompID=@PrCompID and BasePrid=@BsProductID and Wcid=@Wcid 
                and Year(CreatDate)=Year(@CreationDt) and CREATDATE >=@EffDate 
            else if @RestartFrom=3  --- Never ReStart
                Select @BatchMaxVal = isnull(Max(BatchNum),0) from tblbatchmaster where PrCompID=@PrCompID and BasePrid=@BsProductID and Wcid=@Wcid 
            END

            Declare Cur_SttgDetail Cursor For Select BsParaID,ParaType,BatchValue,BatchFormat,Digits from TblBatchNoSettingDetail where BatchID=@BatchID order by SeqNo

            Open Cur_SttgDetail
            Fetch Next From Cur_SttgDetail Into @BsParaID,@ParaType,@BatchValue,@BatchFormat,@Digits

            Set @StrVal=''
            While @@Fetch_Status=0
                begin
                    Set @StrBatchVal=''
                    if @BsParaID=6      -- for Year
                        begin
                            if upper(ltrim(rtrim(@BatchFormat)))='Y'
                                Set @StrBatchVal=Cast(Cast(right(year(@CreationDt),1)as int) as varchar(2))
                            else if upper(ltrim(rtrim(@Batchformat)))='YY'
                                Set @StrBatchVal=Cast(right(year(@CreationDt),2) as varchar(2))
                            else if upper(ltrim(rtrim(@Batchformat)))='YYYY'
                                Set @StrBatchVal=Cast(year(@CreationDt) as varchar(4))
                        end
                    else if @BsParaID=7 -- For Month
                        begin
                            if upper(ltrim(rtrim(@BatchFormat)))='MM'
                                if Cast(month(@CreationDt) as int) < 10
                                    Set @StrBatchVal= '0' + Cast(month(@CreationDt)as varchar(2))
                                else
                                    Set @StrBatchVal= Cast(month(@CreationDt)as varchar(2))
                            else if Upper(ltrim(rtrim(@BatchFormat)))='A'
                                Set @StrBatchVal=(Select Case cast(Month(@CreationDt)as int) 
                                    when 1 then 'A'
                                    when 2 then 'B'
                                    when 3 then 'C'
                                    when 4 then 'D'
                                    when 5 then 'E'
                                    when 6 then 'F'
                                    when 7 then 'G'
                                    when 8 then 'H'
                                    when 9 then 'I'
                                    when 10 then'J'
                                    when 11 then'K'
                                    when 12 then'L' 
                                end)

                        end
                    else if @BsParaID=8
                        begin
                            if @BatchMaxVal=0
                            begin
                                if @RestartFrom=3 
                                   begin 
                                    if @Batchvalue>=100
                                        begin 
                                            Set @StrBatchVal = @BatchValue
                                            Set @BatchNum=Cast(@BatchValue as bigint)
                                        end
                                        else
                                        begin
                                            Set @StrBatchVal = Cast(replicate('0',@Digits-len(@BatchValue)) as varchar(10)) + @BatchValue
                                            Set @BatchNum=Cast(@BatchValue as bigint)
                                        end 
                                    end 
                                else
                                begin 
                                    Set @StrBatchVal = Cast(replicate('0',@Digits-len(@BatchValue)) as varchar(10)) + @BatchValue
                                    Set @BatchNum=Cast(@BatchValue as bigint)
                                end 
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                                    Set @BatchMaxVal=@BatchMaxVal+1                         
                                    Set @StrBatchVal = cast(replicate('0',@Digits-len(cast(@BatchMaxVal as varchar(10)))) as varchar(10)) + Cast(@BatchMaxVal as varchar(10))
                                    Set @BatchNum=@BatchMaxVal
                            end
                        end
                    if @StrBatchVal=''
                        Set @StrBatchVal=@BatchValue
                    Set @StrVal = @StrVal + @StrBatchVal
                    Fetch Next From Cur_SttgDetail Into @BsParaID,@ParaType,@BatchValue,@BatchFormat,@Digits
                end
            Close Cur_SttgDetail
            Deallocate Cur_SttgDetail
            Set @StrBatchNo = cast(@StrVal as varchar(200))         
        end
        Return @RetType
        Return @BatchNum 
        Return @StrBatchNo
end
```

Can you tell me how to call this stored procedure I try but fail

```
                string strsql = "Exec [dbo].[GENRATE_BATCHNO] " + Fid + "," + WcID + "," + PrCompID + "," + BsProductID + ",'" + CreationDate + "' ";
                Reader = dc.GetReader(strsql);
```

Comment: Gosh - what a **huge** mess! Do you really want to *convert* this? I would toss it and try to write it from scratch again - **without** all those cursors!

Comment: Starting point: read the [official MSDN SQL Server Books Online documentation on how to create a table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx#TVF) - basically you need to have a `SELECT` that you can return as a `TABLE` from that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways

- rewrite your sp as a table value function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187650.aspx)
- using an ugly way of OpenQuery see below example

  ```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myfunction    
     (@f1 char(14), @d1 smalldatetime, @tip char(1))
  RETURNS TABLE
  AS
    RETURN
       (SELECT * FROM openquery('SERVER', 'exec dbo.sp @f1, @d1, @tip'))
  ```